# iPhone 5 (a1429) is not giving an option to bypass an update on the start screen. How do I avoid the update?

Tags: ios, iphone

[image: message on start up]When browsing the net the phone displayed a message saying there was a virus/Trojan on the phone and to press ok to remove it. The only option, other than to press ok, was to shut the phone off.

After shutting the phone off it restarted and now says "Software Update Available Tap Ok to get the latest software update". This is most unusual as you normally have an option to bypass any update.

How can I bypass the update? Secondly, is this some sort of virus and how could I tell?

Comment: This question is missing some details, what iOS version are you using? Can you make a screenshot of the Trojan warning if you see it again and what happens when you update the phone software?

Comment: I have no technical knowledge so I cannot say. I am concerned that if I press ok it might corrupt my phone. There is no way I can continue without pressing ok ie the screen will not accept any input. Not very helpful sorry

Comment: I have an image - not of the Trojan but the current issue - how do I add it to this comment please?

Comment: That image is just okay, it just reminds you after turning your device on there's an update available. Just download it and have the most secured iOS around for now.

Comment: ok thanks, great as I have said ok and it now gives the option to install iOS 7.1 thanks for your help, much appreciated!